# Passing a class-based object to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use a directive in angular where I pass a class-based object as a parameter.
When I say "class-based" I mean a function object like in this example:

```
var User = function() {};
var myUser = new User();
```

Now, let's suppose myUser is in the scope of my controller and I have this html.

```
<my:directive myUser="myUser" />
```

Then I define the directive:

```
mainApp.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
            scope: {
            myUser: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/myDirective.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.myUser);
        }
    };
}]);
```

The problem is, I don't see myUser in the controller of the directive.

I have initially blamed the way I declared the parameter with the `=` (it must be used with objects while my object is instead a `function`)

So I tried changing that with the `&` but the problem remains.

Can someone help me out? What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to pass this kind of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you use the attribute in the HTML.

Instead of:

```
myUser="myUser"
```

It should be:

```
my-user="myUser"
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/0fgmham3/

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I didn't notice before, I think I'm just new to directives!
Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Don't worry, took me a while to notice it as well :)